# How to clear contents of a dynamic range minus the header

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to clear contents of a dynamic range minus the header.  The below works well enough though it does not exclude the header.  When I say header, I mean to say I want to clear a column range minus the first row

```
Set wz3= Workbooks("Book1")
wz3.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:G").Clear
```

Changing it to: `wz3.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:G").Clear`
sadly does not skip the header and instead gives an error.

The below also tends to work though you are at a disadvantage of having to manually write down each column you wish to clear. Assuming you had 500 columns and gaps between them calculating this and writing this would be a daunting task...  Any help is really appreciated.

```
Sub Test()
 Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks("Book1")
    With wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Call ColumnSelectAndClear(1)
    Call ColumnSelectAndClear(2)
    ColumnSelectAndClear 3
     ColumnSelectAndClear 4
    End With

End Sub

Public Sub ColumnSelectAndClear(ColNum As Long)
Set wb1 = Workbooks("Book1")
With wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
.Range(.Cells(2, ColNum), .Cells(Rows.Count, ColNum)).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim lRw As Long

lRw = Range("A:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
wz3.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:G" & lRw).Clear
```

Comment: Thanks this does exactly what I was after and I don't have to spend unnecessary time calculating which column is at 10 etc,,

Comment: If it takes care of your issue then mark it as an answer.

Comment: Haha sorry, it wouldn't let me until 5 minutes had passed.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Oh! sorry, I am not aware of that 5 minutes time period.  Thanks for the feedback and marking it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
Public Sub ClearAllBut1stRow(byval Range As Range)
    Range.Resize(Range.Rows.Count-1).Offset(1).Clear
    End With
End Sub
```

So you can just do `ClearAllBut1stRow(Range("A:D"))`.